# python triggers an external executable with unknown installation path

Tags: python, cmd

I am trying to run an executable file via a python script the only problem is that the executable's path is not known to run it from the cmd using subprocess.Popen. Is there a way to find this executable knowing its name and that it is not added in the variable path?

Comment: Please consider extending your question in accordance with [ask], and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why don't you know the path?

Comment: Because I am trying to develop a script that executes another executable that according to its version will be installed in different paths also with different os.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the exe to your path variable. If you don't want to, you could supply the full path to the exe. It is not advisable to search your entire file system for the exe every time you want to run it. However, if you know roughly where the exe is, you could search there like so:

```
import glob
import subprocess
my_exe = ""
search_paths = [r'C:\Program Files\MyCompanyName\*\bin\myexe.exe','/usr/bin/myexe','/usr/local','/opt/myexe/bin/myexe']
for search_path in search_paths:
    for exe in glob.glob(search_path):
        my_exe = exe
        break
    if len(my_exe) != 0:
        break
if len(my_exe) != 0:
    subprocess.run([my_exe,'-my-args'])
else:
    print("Didn't find the exe")
```

Another option is to make an environment variable with the path to the exe and then use this to get it in python

```
import os
import subprocess
my_exe = os.environ['MY_EXE_PATH']
if len(my_exe) != 0:
    if os.path.exists(my_exe):
        subprocess.run([my_exe,'-my-args'])
    else:
        print("Invalid path in MY_EXE_PATH")
else:
    print("Please set the MY_EXE_PATH variable")
```

Comment: the problem is knowing that my executable will be installed in program files on windows this may not work when running it on another os system.

Comment: I added an edit that would work better cross-platform

Comment: 'MyCompanyName\*\bin\myexe.exe' this i don't understand what does it does. when i tried with notepad i got this problem 'TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list'

Comment: I fixed the typo. It should run now